# Meaning of correctly classified instances weka

Tags: weka

I recently started using weka and I'm trying to classify tweets into positive or negative using Naive Bayes. So I have a training set with tweets that I gave the label for and a test set with tweets that all have the label "positive". When I ran Naive Bayes, I get the following results:

Correctly classified instances:     69 92%
Incorrectly classified instances:   6   8%

Then if I change the labels of the tweets in the test set to "negative" and ran again Naive Bayes, the results are inversed:

Correctly classified instances:     6   8%
Incorrectly classified instances:   69  92%

I thought that correctly classified instances show the accuracy of Naive Bayes and that it should be the same no matter the labels of the tweets in test set. Is there something wrong with my data or I don't understand correctly the meaning of correctly classified instances?

Thanks a lot for your time,

Nantia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The labels on the test set are supposed to be the actual correct classification. Performance is computed by asking the classifier to give its best guess about the classification for each instance in the test set. Then the predicted classifications are compared to the actual classifications to determine accuracy. Therefore, if you flip the 'correct' values that you give it, the results will be flipped as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Junnux & Antimony for the quick answers! The test set is created this way: I give a search term to my program, twitter api returns tweets that include this term, these tweets compose my test set and then Naive Bayes runs. So I am not able to add the correct labels for the test set. If I understood you well, in this case I will be able to get the classifier's answers for the labels of the test set, but I won't be able to evaluate accuracy. Did I get it right?

Comment: You're correct, assuming you have labels for the training set at least. If you don't even have that, then you're taking the wrong approach. Naive Bayes is an algorithm for supervised learning. If you don't have labels, then what you are looking for is __unsupervised__ learning, which requires a different set of algorithms, and in general gives much worse results. I'd suggest either finding a way to label your data or google for unsupervised learning.

Comment: Yes, my purpose is supervised learning so I have labels for my trainig set. Thanks a lot again! You really helped me sort out a few things. :)

Comment: @user1644316: Try splitting up your labelled data in a training and test set, or use crossvalidation, to get an idea of how good your classifier works. Afterwards, you can train on the entire labelled dataset to classify new unseen data, and assume that the accuracy is similar. Antimony: +1.

Comment: @Antimony Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72715345/accuracy-degrade-with-highly-skewed-data-after-handling-imbalance-problem/72722276?noredirect=1#comment128454918_72722276 question?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your training set, 69.92% of your instances are classified as positive. If the labels  for the test set, that is **the correct answers**, indicate that they are all positive, then that makes 69.92% correct. If the test set (and thus the classification) is the same, but you switch the correct answers, then of course, the percentage correct will also be the opposite.

Keep in mind that in order to evaluate a classifier, you need the true labels of the test set. Otherwise you can't compare the classifier's answers with the true answers. It seems to me that you might have misunderstood this. You can obtain the labels for unseen data, if that is what you want, but in that case you can't evaluate classifier accuracy.

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72715345/accuracy-degrade-with-highly-skewed-data-after-handling-imbalance-problem/72722276?noredirect=1#comment128454918_72722276 in this question?