# Accuracy degrade with highly skewed data after handling imbalance problem

Tags: classification, weka

After preprocessing my data, like missing value replacement and outlier detection I partitioned my data using randomized and remove percentage filter using WEKA. My dataset is a highly skewed dataset with imbalance ratio 6:1 corresponding to negative and positive class. If I classify the data using Naive Bayes classifier without handling class imbalance problem I got 83% accuracy with recall 0.623. However if I handle class imbalance(after balance 1:1) with supervised -instances - resample or supervised -instances - spreadsub sample filter and then apply Naive Bayes for classification accuracy degrade by 77% with recall ratio 0.456.

I cannot understand why accuracy degrade when handle class imbalance ratio?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a class imbalance of 6:1 then the majority class is 6/7 = 85.7%. Just by predicting the majority class (eg using ZeroR) you would get an accuracy slightly better than what NaiveBayes achieves.

After balancing your dataset, NaiveBayes reports 77% accuracy, which is well above the 50% for predicting the majority class.

NaiveBayes has, in some sense, actually improved.

Comment: How could 77% be better than 83%? I have already got 83% accuracy with the imbalance dataset. On top of that if I apply the feature selection method and select some features like 30 features from a 60 features dataset I got like 85% accuracy with an imbalanced dataset. However, whenever I tried to balance the dataset the performance degrade. Is not it weird? Because balancing a dataset should improve accuracy.

Comment: With skewed data, NaiveBayes is **worse** than simply predicting the majority class (83% < 85.7%). In other words, a useless model. With balanced data, NaiveBayes is much better than just predicting the majority class (77% > 50%). In other words, a useful model. Summary statistics like accuracy have to be treated carefully, as they don't tell the whole story. Last, but not least: you have two very different datasets and you can't just compare the two accuracies. Such a comparison makes only sense for algorithms that were built on the **same** dataset.

Comment: The accuracy that I have mentioned was the test data accuracy. The sampling techniques have been applied in the training data. Therefore, The accuracy and recall that I have mentioned are for the same dataset not for two different datasets.